# Postgresql - where and order by clause not using index or index incorrect

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a large table (>50M) with the basic structure and other columns but these are the columns that I use to do the `where` and `order by` clauses in the query

Table and index:

```sql
create table t1
(
    id           varchar not null
        primary key,
    num bigint
);

create index t1_id_number_desc_index
    on transactions (num desc, id desc);
```

I have the use case of pagination results in the api, returning the data of this table on pages and it should be sorted by the `number` field, the query has 2 inputs to the pagination works: the limit number per page and continuation token (the last `id` from the previous page result, ex: `id > 'xyz'`)

query with the input of the previous `id`:

```sql
select *
from t1 t
where
      id > 'xyz'
  and
      id in (select distinct transaction_id from events where address = 'dksaijdiasjda9128231')
order by num desc, id desc
limit 50;
```

The select `select distinct transaction_id from events where address = 'dksaijdiasjda9128231'` can be replaced of an array of id too by the application.

I have the index `t1_id_number_desc_index` to get the results alright sorted with the filter of `id > value`. But it wasn't working and doing a next step of sorting in the `explain plan` query, the next pages are returning numbers bigger than the previous pages, so it appears to be using just the index of the primary key to filter by the continuation token.

Can be a wrong index config or just the pg doesn't properly with it (maybe I need to concat the 2 columns in the id field `num + _ + id`, ex: `111_xyz` and use just only this field to do the where and order by)?

Comment: No need for the index to be in descending order.

Comment: "...to get the results alright sorted with the filter of id > value..." -- well, no. For an index to be used the engine needs to consider the scan range to be contiguous. In your case, since there ids need still to be matched against another subquery that won't be true. Please post the entire query. It's not possible to optimize parts of a query only.

Comment: @TheImpaler updated the query with the subquery. The main problem is just not getting all the results ordered by the `num` if it uses the limit and continuation where.

Comment: Please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) for this query